# How limit select permission for a sql server user on the same table per data set

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017, sql-server-2019

I have a dataset in one table as follow, I am looking for a way to limit the select permission base on column and dataset or have a way to know from current context the caller stack.

Table x:

- Id age type
- 1   AGE1     male
- 2   age2.    Female
- 3   Age3.    male
- 4   Age4.    Female

Table y:

- Id Size
- 1  Size1
- 2  Size2
- 3  size3
- 4  size4

For user x:
I need the user x to read table y and table x in case male and read table y and table x without age if dataset is female.

My view:
Male query

```
Select * from table y inner join table x on y.Id = x.id
Where x.Type = 'male'
```

Female query

```
Select y.*, x.id, x.type from table y inner join table x on y.Id = x.id
Where x.Type = 'female'
```

Knowing that in the above view I need to grant access to table y and x cause developer using same table x for same user x.

Or I can use Roles but need to know if the execution stack from view or table.

In the Security Role:
If calling is female view then deny on age else
Allow *

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly want you want to achieve, I think this is the solution:

```
select y.*, x.id, x.type, IIF(x.type = 'female', -1, x.age) age
from tabley y
    join tablex x on y.Id = x.id
```

this will show -1 for age for 'female' records

Comment: Actually if developer make select from table he will be able to see the female age where I am looking for a solution to hide this data only for females

Comment: if so, I suggest creating a view from above query and grant permission only to that view, not to underlying tables...

Comment: You can not do that. Remember you have male need to be full query *, you can not do this in view regardless of table